# iphone dev create an array accessable from a number of View Controllers

Tags: iphone, arrays

I have an array arryImages which I would only like to declare once and access it from a number of view controllers, but I can't figure out where to place it.

I have a separate class (Variables.m) which contains the following code

```
 @implementation Variables

//images array
arryImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [UIImage imageNamed: @"ico-company.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed: @"ico-value.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed: @"ico-date.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed: @"ico-notes.png"], nil];

@end
```

In my viewcontroller class (which I want to access the array) I have added:

```
#import "Variables.h"
```

I tried playing with @synthesize, but I can't access the array arrayImages.

(Using the call imageView2.image = [arryImages objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];) Ps. this works perfect when its just above the code, but not in a separate class.

What am I missing?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your array as a property. Synthesize it and initialize in your ViewDidLoad Method.

i.e. the header

```
@interface AddFriendViewController : UIViewController {
 NSArray *arryImages;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSarray *arryImages ;

@end
```

the implementation:

```
@synthesize arryImages;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arryImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
          [UIImage imageNamed: @"ico-company.png"],
          [UIImage imageNamed: @"ico-value.png"],
          [UIImage imageNamed: @"ico-date.png"],
          [UIImage imageNamed: @"ico-notes.png"], nil];
}
```

If you want to share a variable between views, you should put in your app delegate and access it from there.

```
NSArray *arryImages = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] arryImages];
```

Comment: I am still trying to figure out exactly what you mean. And I want this to work from numerous viewcontrollers.

Are you saying the first header should be in the appdelegate and the second bit in ViewDidLoad? As in i should create it? I only have applicationDidFinishStarting

And then does the third code go in the view controller I want to access arryImages?

For example, lets say the view controllers I want to access arryImages are :
DetailViewController.m
and 
EditViewController.m 
and I only want to declare the array once.

what code goes where?

Regards

Comment: You declare your NSArray in your AppDelegate Header, init and fill it in your AppDelegate  Implementation and access it by using the code I posted above: "NSArray *arryImages = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] arryImages];"

Comment: and yes: it's not viewdidload but applicationDidFinishStarting in your app delegate.

Comment: ok its working ;) Your second comment help clear things up a bit. The appDelegate @property should be '@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arryImages;' with Array capitalised. I declared the array in applicationDidFinishLaunching, as  "self.arryImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ..." and the third bit i put in just before where I needed the NSArray.

Thanks for the help!